# iPad:Popover sample to iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I am developing an app which will be used on both iPhone and iPad.

Today I've found that I should use Popover for iPad instead of PickerView on an action sheet.

I am trying to use a sample app use it on iOS5,  but I have been getting an error;

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "2-view-5" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Do you know what exactly i need to do to fix that?
And, do you have any recommendation of popover examples for iOS5?

```
UYLMasterViewController.m
#import "UYLMasterViewController.h"
#import "UYLDetailViewController.h"

@implementation UYLMasterViewController

@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark === View Management ===
#pragma mark -

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
self.detailViewController = nil;

}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark === Table View Delegates ===
#pragma mark -

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %u", row+1];
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSUInteger item = [indexPath row] +1;
NSNumber *detailItem = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:item];

if (self.detailViewController)
{
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = detailItem;
}
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't modify anything from the sample app, this is quite strange.
Anyway, I usually get this error when I forgot to set an IBOutlet connection from the table to the controller UITableViewController.

It is likely that you delete it by mistake, or Xcode lost its connection for some reason (it happens).

See if UYLMasterViewController.h is a UITableViewController. If yes, then the UITableView must be the first view in nib file, directly connected to the 'view' IBOutlet property of the controller.
Otherwise if UITableView is inside a UIView then you get the exact error you mentioned.

A probable solution, if UITableView is not the main view, would be to set UYLMasterViewController as a normal UIViewController and give it all the delegate accessor, then drag a connection from the UITableView to the controller, you will see that you have two options delegate and datasource, you need both.

Comment: Hi, i couldn't find any example for iOS5 so using a sample for ios4. so when i download a sample I have to convert the codes suitable for ios5. I created IBOutlet and connected to the tableView on the page, no luck.

Comment: Uhm, is the controller you are to connect to a UITableViewController ? If yes there should already be a property called tableView, you should connect the UITableView to that property, rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Not sure what tableview i need. I edited the sample code i was using (it's one of them...and not Apple's), and using storyboard. I am not sure how to connect the tableview on the ViewController.

Comment: If you create a new project and use the "Utility" template and set to Universal, it uses a modal view as fullscreen in iPhone, and as a popover for iPad. That's where I would start, since you're looking for an example.

Comment: Which is great, because it only uses 1 NIB for both.

Comment: oh that's nice! I would use it tomorrow. thanks for your comment.